# Create array using for loop

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to generate integer array using for loop. Here is my code:

```
int total = 20;

for(int x = 0; x < total; x++)
{
   NSArray arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:total]];
}
```

With the above implementation I get only one object in array, the last one. What to do so arr to contain the numbers from 1 to 20 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int total = 20;

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int x = 0; x < total; x++)
{
   [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];
}

// release the array when you are done with it.
```

Comment: `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` instead of `[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`. Cheers

Comment: @Flex_Addicted: you know that you can edit a response from typos =) I will change it, thanx m8!

Comment: yeah, but you can edit a question only if 6 characters are modified at least. Maybe I'm wrong... Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize your array outside of the loop rather than inside the loop.

Change your code to this:

```
int total = 20;
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int x = 0; x < total; x++)
   [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're recreating the array every time.  Make the `NSArray` an iVar or initialize it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`NSArray` is an immutable class (it means you cannot add/remove objects runtime) and what you are doing here is quite strange. You create a new array inside the loop.

You could use a `NSMutableArray` but externally to the loop. In this manner you have a reference outside the loop and you can add objects to it. `NSMutableArray` is mutable. You can change objects runtime.

```
NSMutableArray* numberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int x = 0; x < total; x++)
{
   [numberArray addObject:[NSSnumber numberWithInt:x]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutablearray arrayWithCapacity:total];
for(int x = 0; x < total; x++)
{
   [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];
}
```

At every loop you created new array with one object. in this example you create array once and than just add objects to it.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  You should store x in the array, not total or else you'll have 20 objects all with the value of 20.

Comment: Perhaps, `[NSNumber numberWithInt: i]` was originally meant, but YMMV.

Comment: May want to explain what the OP was doing wrong, and why your answer solves that problem, just for completeness's sake.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are creating a new `NSArray` and assigning it to  `NSArray *arr`. `+arrayWithObjects:` method create a new array. NSArray is not mutable , you should use `NSMutableArray`.

> NSArray creates static arrays, and NSMutableArray creates dynamic
>   arrays.

```
NSMuatbleArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i =0 ; i<20 ; ++i)
{
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```